# How does Flink recover the state of a streaming job in case of a failure?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to use State in Flink (i.e. ValueState) to save some information of each keyed event.
But I am worring that if the program breaks, then how can I get this information back ?

Comment: Please read the Flink documentation: [Data Streaming Fault Tolerance](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/internals/stream_checkpointing.html) and [Checkpointing](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/checkpointing.html).

Comment: @FabianHueske I tried to read the docs, maybe not enough, I was a little confused how it works, I don't know if you have some simple phrase to explain it ?

Comment: There's a succinct summary here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/concepts/programming-model.html#checkpoints-for-fault-tolerance